# ios can app developer name be our studio name?

Tags: ios

We use a personal apple developer account and we used to submit apps in my name. Now we want to use our studio name instead of someone's real name, but our studio name has not yet registered. Can We do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, you can definitely not set the Individual Developer Account's name to your company name.
I thought about that too but as they ask you like a hundred times whether you are sure this is your legal name you cannot set it to anything but your actual name. I suggest using the company's CEO / representative's name for it.

Once you have created a legally effective company you can create a new Company's Developer Account and **transfer the applications** from the Individual's Account to your new one.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

If you change your account to be related to a Company instead of an individual, the name will be changed to the name of the Company.

You can find more information here:
https://developer.apple.com/support/account/

Comment: The problem is we do not have a company yet. Can I change the individual name to our studio name?

Comment: As stated on the FAQ, you will most likely be asked to present business documents. Depending on where you live, setting up a company can be very simple. Either way, it is a requirement to change the name.